# solving a system of non-linear partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have following a system of nonlinear partial differential equations
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) &= (p + q f(x,y))(1-f(x,y))\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) &= -(p + q (1-f(x,y)))f(x,y)
\end{align*} $$
where $p$ and $q$ are non negative numbers. I could find a solution when $ p = 0$ that is
$$f(x,y) = \frac{e^{qx}}{e^{qx} + e^{qy}}.$$
But I could not solve when $p>0$...

Comment: It's not a system of nonlinear PDEs, its two separate ODEs with $y$ and $x$ acting as parameters in the first and second equations, respectively, both of which are separable and can be solved using partial fractions.